# Why background image isn't responsive to browser resize?

Tags: html, css

My background image and its text are responsive to width resizing as long as the browser height is sized to the max. But when decreasing browser (such as Chrome) height the background image doesn't fit the whole window anymore. Any suggestions help!

```css
#header {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(/img/roses.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    height: 100vh;
}
.name h1 {
    font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
    font-size: 500%;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10%;
}
.name p {
    font-family: 'Play', sans-serif;
    font-size: 150%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5%;
}
.navigation p {
    display: inline;
}
.navigation {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10%;
}
.contents:hover {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.contents {
    color: whitesmoke;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Media Queries */
@media (max-width: 33.9em) {
    .name h1 {
        font-size: 300%;
    }
    .name p {
        font-size: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<section id="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 name">
                <h1>Temple Naylor</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 name">
                <p>I create Web-designs with a sense of Feng-Shui in mind; resulting for a intuitive, responsive, harmonious, experience for users across the world. <br>
                  NOW AVAILABLE FOR YOU</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 navigation hidden-md-down">
                <p><a class="contents" href="#">ABOUT</a> / </p>
                <p><a class="contents" href="#">WORK</a> / </p>
                <p><a class="contents" href="#">CONTACT</a> / </p>
                <p><a class="contents" href="#">PHOTOGRAPHY</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Here is what it looks like when browser height is shortened http://imgur.com/a/2pSYB

Comment: you can use `background-size 100% 100%` but in this case image will stretch, or you'll have to adjust the height as per the image height width to fit in the container.

Comment: create a fiddle with real image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close but a little off. You want background-size: cover

```
body {
  background: url(http://www.hd-wallpapersdownload.com/script/bulk-upload/3d-wallpaper-rose-dowload.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/norcaljohnny/z7smu750/)

**UPDATE:**
I was told the OP would like to keep text from scrolling as it shrunk, so here is a version of the text in VW opposed to PX so it becomes responsive as well.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/norcaljohnny/2ne1uao3/) with responsive text.

Comment: This creates the same problem when you maximize the window again :( http://imgur.com/a/2pSYB

Comment: I get full screen every time. No hiccups here.

Comment: Would this be due just to my image possibly?

Comment: I could not see the full URL of your image so the one I used is 1920x1080. You can try to fork the demo, and the image pic I used replace it with your image URL, then test it. If it works than you know it is not your image.

Comment: ACtually I am a little confused, When i used your code on jsfiddle it was for full screen and now with your demo it is just the header with an image. Are you looking to have a fullscreen pic of just the header..

Comment: I'm sorry sir, your code actually executed perfectly. I was looking for a solution to this problem with out having to use a scroll bar if possible and having ALL the content in the browser page be responsive to the resizing. But I will definitely mark you down as an answer.

Comment: No problem, if you do not want to force a scrollbar situation, adjust the text using vw instead of pixels.This gives it a responsiveness to the text..in turn making it not need to scroll as it minimizes.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the lead!

Comment: Check out the update in the answer, new demo with responsive text. I think this will give what you want without scrolling. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

you may want to use `background-size: 100%;`

**updated**

remove `height: 100vh;` from header and this should fix the problem 
see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/27008/)

you may want to add `background-position: fixed` if this suits you, [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/27009/)

see this great tut https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: No, this didn't help :(

Comment: @YoungCoder checkout my updated answer ur bg img wont cutoff even browser height is small

Comment: This is great but when you maximize the browser again the background image doesn't fill the whole screen.

Answer (score 1):

When you resize the window, `#header` is more than 100% of the browser height due the `.container` inside, therefore the scrolling.

To fix it, add

```
#header { overflow: hidden; }
body { margin: 0; }
```

or get the `.container` out of the `#header`